# How do I change Guice bindings for functional tests?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, guice

I'm working on a Play (v. 2.4) application with Guice as DI provider. Everything runs fine however I have a set of functional tests running with ScalaTestPlus and I would like to replace some dependencies when the test are running. The tests are written by extending `OneServerPerSuite` class as they check my REST API.

Is there any way to have other dependencies during tests?

**EDIT: Sample code:**

Sample controller:

```
class UserController @Inject()(userService: UserService) extends AbstractController { ... }
```

And dependecy definition in module:

```
bind(classOf[UserService]) to (classOf[ProdUserService])
```

My tests are like this:

```
class ApiTest extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite {

    "User API should" must {
         "get User's data" in {
             (...) //calling to an endpoint and verifying response
         }
     }
}
```

I would like to have `ProdUserService` replaced with other implementation but only in tests.

Comment: Do you have any sample code?

Comment: I've updated the question with sample code.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.inject.bind
import play.api.Application
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import database.AccountDAO
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.Mode

class ApiTest extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite {

 def app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder() // you create your app
        .configure(
          Configuration.from(
            Map( // a custom configuration for your tests only
              "slick.dbs.default.driver" -> "slick.driver.H2Driver$",
              "slick.dbs.default.db.driver" -> "org.h2.Driver",
              "slick.dbs.default.db.connectionPool" -> "disabled",
              "slick.dbs.default.db.keepAliveConnection" -> "true",
              "slick.dbs.default.db.url" -> "jdbc:h2:mem:test",
              "slick.dbs.default.db.user" -> "sa",
              "slick.dbs.default.db.password" -> "")))
        .bindings(bind[UserService].to[UserServiceImpl]) // here you can define your bindings for an actual implementation (note the use of square brackets)
        .in(Mode.Test)
        .build()


    "User API should" must {
         "get User's data" in new WithApplication(app) {
            // if you want to get the controller with everything injected
            val app2controller = Application.instanceCache[controllers.UserController]
            val userController = app2controller(app) // with this you get the controller with the service injected

             (...) //calling to an endpoint and verifying response
         }
     }
}
```